# Implementing function within a specific column in an sql table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a student's table where there are 7

```
    columns: Reg_No(i.e.Register number of    
          student),Mark1,Mark2,Mark3,Best1,Best2,Total.
```

The data Reg_No, Mark1, Mark2 and Mark3 are retrieved from database. 
Am just looking for a way to select the maximum 2 marks from Mark1, Mark2 and Mark3 and fill 
them in Best1 and Best2 columns.

Finally i shoud produce the added result of Mark1 and Mark2 in **Total** column. Pls suggest me a way.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you would like an SQL answer.

> SELECT   Reg_No,   Mark1,   Mark2,   MAX(Mark1) AS Best1,   MAX(Mark2)
>   AS Best2,   SUM(Mark1 + Mark2) AS Total FROM Students GROUP BY Reg_No,
>   Mark1, Mark2

This query probably isn't very useful, though, since it mixes aggregated data with the data to be aggregated.  If you only need to see each unique student's best and total grades, a better query would be:

> SELECT   Reg_No,   MAX(Mark1) AS Best1,   MAX(Mark2) AS Best2,
>   SUM(Mark1 + Mark2) AS Total FROM Students GROUP BY Reg_No

Comment: OP is not expecting a best of a column value from all rows but best of values in each of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `greatest` and `least` functions applied on the field values of a row.

***Example***:

```
select
 @m1 := 55 m1, @m2 := 42 m2, @m3 := 66 m3,
 @b1 := greatest( @m1, @m2, @m3 ) b1,
 @b2 := ( ( @total := @m1 + @m2 + @m3 ) 
          - ( @b1 + least( @m1, @m2, @m3 ) ) 
        ) b2,
 @total total;

+----+----+----+------+------+-------+
| m1 | m2 | m3 | b1   | b2   | total |
+----+----+----+------+------+-------+
| 55 | 42 | 66 |   66 |   55 |   163 |
+----+----+----+------+------+-------+
```

Try this on your `students` table:

```
select  
  Reg_No, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3, 
  @b1 := greatest( Mark1, Mark2, Mark3 ) Best1, 
  @b2 := ( ( @total := Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3 )  
           - ( @b1 + least( Mark1, Mark2, Mark3 ) ) 
         ) Best2, 
  @total Total
from students
```

***Refer to***:

1. [MySQL: GREATEST(value1,value2,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

   - Return the largest argument
2. [MySQL: LEAST(value1,value2,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

   - Return the smallest argument