# How can I assign value to a variable using aggregate function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, where-clause

This is my table structure and data.

```
create table StudentInformation
(
    sId INT(5),
    name VARCHAR(50),
    sClass VARCHAR(10),
    maths INT(5),
    physics INT(5),
    chemistry INT(5)
);

INSERT INTO StudentInformation
values
(1, 'Jai', '11th', 60, 75, 65),
(2, 'Leela', '12th', 91, 87, 94),
(3, 'Suresh', '11th', 75, 68, 70),
(4, 'Ramesh', '11th', 50, 67, 55),
(5, 'Janki', '12th', 78, 89, 78),
(6, 'Lalu', '12th', 30, 38, 45),
(7, 'Amit', '11th', 91, 95, 93),
(8, 'Komal', '11th', 66, 78, 74),
(9, 'Sanjay', '12th', 25, 40, 35);
```

Now I want to calculate average marks for each class.
I have tried this query :

```
SELECT
sClass class,
@var := sum(maths+physics+chemistry)/(count(sid)*3) as avgMarksPerSubject,
@var as variableValue,
count(sid) as numberOfStudents
FROM StudentInformation
#where @var > 65
group by sClass;
```

Use of variable is compulsory here as this is just an example of my actual task.
Now I would like to have those records which have more than 65 marks.
Is it possible by using variable in `WHERE` clause ?
I am not getting actual data in `@var`, how can I use it in `WHERE` clause ?
You can try sql query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfde9/14).
Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: There is one variable called @var which will be shared with all the rows, so the value for the first row will be over written by subsequent rows values. Further your WHERE clause will happen before the aggregate functions are carried out (change it to HAVING avgMarksPerSubject > 65).

Comment: That means I can not use variable in such kind of case, right ?

Comment: No you are not. They can be used to carry over a value from one row to the next, and assigned to an field in the SELECT, but the variable itself is over written each time it is assigned to. Use of a variable here to get the results you want is completely unnecessary. What is your real requirement that makes a variable compulsory?

Comment: In my actual task, I have to join more than 20 tables and calculate some parameters for each row and further use it for division and multiplication. So I want to avoid using repetition of these kind of parameters.

Comment: Don't think you are going to be able to do it using variables. Probably need to do joins against sub queries, with the sub queries calculating the parameters for each group of rows.

Comment: I agree, but does repetition affect to performance of that query ?

Comment: If you are doing a correlated sub query then yes (ie, it is doing the query per row), but with a non correlated sub query probably not (unless you query contains the same sub query multiple times). Without details of you actual query it is difficult to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Using a user defined *session* variable in `where` clause is only possible when it is *pre initialized*. Unless otherwise, due to the [*SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations*](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm), the variable will be having a default `NULL` and the condition may not satisfy the results as expected.

```
set @var:=0;

SELECT
      sClass class,
      @var := cast(sum(maths+physics+chemistry)
                   /(count(sid)*3) as decimal(6,2)
              ) as avgMarksPerSubject,
      @var as variableValue,
      count(sid) as numberOfStudents
FROM  StudentInformation
where @var < 65
group by sClass
;

+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
| CLASS | AVGMARKSPERSUBJECT | VARIABLEVALUE | NUMBEROFSTUDENTS |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
| 11th  |              72.13 |             0 |                5 |
| 12th  |              60.83 |             0 |                4 |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Here you can clearly see that the variable is not assigned any value per row and from the value calculated in the previous column expression.

You can see its side effects by running the following query:

```
select * from (
  SELECT
      sClass class,
      @var := cast(sum(maths+physics+chemistry)
                   /(count(sid)*3) as decimal(6,2)
              ) as avgMarksPerSubject,
      @var as variableValue,
      count(sid) as numberOfStudents
  FROM StudentInformation
  group by sClass
) r where avgMarksPerSubject > 65

+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
| CLASS | AVGMARKSPERSUBJECT | VARIABLEVALUE | NUMBEROFSTUDENTS |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
| 11th  |              72.13 |         60.83 |                5 |
+-------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

**Example** @ [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfde9/49):

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, But after removing where clause, I got same value - @var or (variableValue) - for each class. Check out this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfde9/48

Comment: Yes. Please read through the suggested [*SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations*](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm). The earlier result was because of `where` presence and was executed first.

Comment: Check out different behavior of queries. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfde9/53 Can you explain ?

Comment: Not exactly sure on the precedence of `@var`, the session variable. Sounds like carries from the latest calculated row but not column expression. See last query executed @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfde9/54

Comment: That's what I am wondering. I am not able to store value in `@var` for each row.

Comment: This seems worth for asking a query on this on SO.

Comment: Also see one of my answers on [usage of session variables at row level](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22179331/767881).