# MySQL left joining subquery to group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a requirement where I need o group data into equal number ob rows. As mysql doesn't have `rownum()` I'm simulating this behaviour:

```
SET @row:=6; 
SELECT MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, MAX(agg.value) AS value, COUNT(agg.value) AS count 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT timestamp, value, @row:=@row+1 AS row 
        FROM data 
        WHERE channel_id=52 AND timestamp >= 0 ORDER BY timestamp
    ) AS agg 
GROUP BY row div 8
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Note: according to [Can grouped expressions be used with variable assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108413/can-grouped-expressions-be-used-with-variable-assignments) this query may not be 100% correct, but it *does* work.

An additional requirement is to calculate the row difference between the grouped sets. I've looked for a solution joining the same table with a subquery:

```
SET @row:=6; 
SELECT MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, MAX(agg.value) AS value, COUNT(agg.value) AS count 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT timestamp, value, @row:=@row+1 AS row 
        FROM data 
        WHERE channel_id=52 AND timestamp >= 0 ORDER BY timestamp
    ) AS agg 
LEFT JOIN data AS prev
    ON prev.channel_id = agg.channel_id
    AND prev.timestamp = (
        SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
        FROM data
        WHERE data.channel_id = agg.channel_id
            AND data.timestamp < MIN(agg.timestamp)
    )
GROUP BY row div 8
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Unfortunately that errors:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'agg.channel_id' in 'on clause'
```

Any idea how this query could be written?

Comment: It should just be a matter of exposing `channel_id` in the select list for the `agg` subquery. Currentl you only have it in the `WHERE` clause. (I haven't analyzed whether that will give you the desired result, but it will clear the 1054 error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this version:

```
SELECT MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, MAX(agg.value) AS value, COUNT(agg.value) AS count, COALESCE(prev.timestamp, 0) AS prev_timestamp
FROM (SELECT d.*, @row:=@row+1 AS row 
      FROM data d CROSS JOIN
           (select @row := 6) vars
      WHERE channel_id = 52 AND timestamp >= 0 ORDER BY timestamp
     )  agg LEFT JOIN
    data prev
    ON prev.channel_id = agg.channel_id AND
       prev.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
                         FROM data
                         WHERE data.channel_id = agg.channel_id AND
                               data.timestamp < agg.timestamp
                        )
GROUP BY row div 8
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

This includes all the columns in the subquery.  And it puts the variable initialization in the same query.

Comment: I like the cross join, but "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @andig . . . That is in your subquery.  I'm not sure what that is supposed to do, but you can't put a correlated subquery in a `from` clause.

Comment: I need the subquery to calculate the timestamp row by row difference to the previous, aggregated row. I've rewritten your answer to eliminate the error and deliver the desired result.

Comment: just tried this on my production database. On a table with only 40k records and channel_id/timestamp index event the explain plan won't return. Seems the subquery is severely killing performance here?

Comment: The explain plan not returning is a different issue.  The performance of the query should be reasonable.  That index should work for both subqueries and the amount of data is not enormously large.

Comment: I've put the performance question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457442/how-to-find-previous-record-n-per-group-maxtimestamp-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You never selected `channel_id` from your sbuquery, so it's not returned to the parent query, and is therefore invisible. Try

```
SELECT MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, MAX(agg.value) AS value, COUNT(agg.value) AS count 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT timestamp, value, @row:=@row+1 AS row, channel_id
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^-- need this
        FROM data
```

Since MySQL only sees and uses the fields you explicitly return from that subquery, and will NOT "dig deeper" into the table underlying the query, you need to select/return all of the fields you'll be using the parent queries.