# Tracking current and previous status

Tags: mysql, sql, informatica

I have a table which keeps the **status** and **created_timestamp** corresponding to a **process_id**. One row is inserted as soon as the process status changes. So, there are as many rows with same **process_id** as there are statuses associated with it.
I want to create another **table/view** using this data which has one single row corresponding to a **process_id**, its current status and its previous status. I need to make a Informatica job for this, but a SQL query will be just as helpful. 
Sample Input:

```
Process_id | Status     | Created 
         1 | In_queue   | 2014-08-01 00:01:01 
         1 | Started    | 2014-08-01 01:03:01 
         1 | In_process | 2014-08-01 01:50:20 
         1 | Complete   | 2014-08-01 03:10:20 

Sample Output: 
Process_id | Previous_status | Current_status | Updated 
         1 | In_process      | Complete       | 2014-08-01 03:10:20
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make a computer science job for this"? SQL is computer science.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849098/mysql-how-get-value-in-previous-row-and-value-in-next-row

Comment: @mTorres That question is about knowing the ID of the row you want the adjacent rows for. It doesn't really address getting the newest row and the previous before that.

Comment: Here's a question about getting the latest 2 rows for each group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457442/how-to-find-previous-record-n-per-group-maxtimestamp-timestamp You just need to use that method, and then pivot the result to get both statuses in the same row.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for how to pivot the results. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group has lots more examples of getting the latest N rows per group.

Comment: I think this problem is deceptively tricky

Comment: @Barmar I meant Informatica... I don't know how the hell did it end up as computer science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Process_id, Previous_status, Current_status, Updated 
FROM (
    SELECT
    Process_id, 
    Status AS Current_status, 
    Created AS Updated,
    @prev_state AS Previous_status,
    @prev_state := Status 
    FROM
    your_table t
    , (select @prev_state := null) var_init
    WHERE Process_id = 1
    ORDER BY Created
) sq
```

UPDATE:

To do it for all Process_ids and just get the latest record for each Process_id you can use this:

```
SELECT sq.Process_id, sq.Previous_status, sq.Current_status, sq.Updated 
FROM (
    SELECT
    Process_id, 
    Status AS Current_status, 
    Created AS Updated,
    @prev_state := if(@prev_process != Process_id, null, @prev_state),
    @prev_state AS Previous_status,
    @prev_state := Status,
    @prev_process := Process_id
    FROM
    your_table t
    , (select @prev_state := null, @prev_process := null) var_init
    ORDER BY Process_id, Created
) sq
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Process_id, MAX(Created) AS max_created
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Process_id
) max_c
ON sq.Process_id = max_c.Process_id AND sq.Updated = max_c.max_created
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Since, the data volume is significant, I'd rather go with this method only. Two questions though: 1. How can we do it for all process_ids instead of mentioning only 1? 2. I have one more columns like status..... Update on that also need to be captured. Is it possible in the same query?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your first question. For second question just add more variables as needed.

Comment: Hey... its for process_id=1 only... you can slightly edit the filter to correct it. Other than that, it's the right word for this solution is "cool" :) Thanks a lot.!

Comment: Yes, copy&paste error. I also added Process_id to the `ORDER BY` clause. This is important!

Answer (score 0):

Performance aside, here's how I'd do it...

```
SELECT a.process_id
     , a.status
     , a.created
     , b.status prev_status
     , b.created prev_created
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.process_id = x.process_id
          AND y.created >= x.created
        GROUP
           BY x.process_id
            , x.created
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.process_id = x.process_id
          AND y.created >= x.created
        GROUP
           BY x.process_id
            , x.created
     ) b
    ON b.process_id = a.process_id
 WHERE b.rank = a.rank + 1
   AND a.rank = 1;
```

On a larger dataset, I'd probably go with a more fancyPantsy  solution